# Haystack index objects using their reverse relation

Tags: python, django, search, tastypie, django-haystack

I have a two models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.TextField()

class Response(models.Model):
    response_text = models.TextField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='responses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have one haystack search index to index all of the `Question`'s `question_text`:

```
class QuestionIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    question_text = indexes.CharField(model_attr='question_text')
    def get_model(self):
        return Question
```

How do I index all of the `response_text` so that when I search for `Question`s, I get all of the questions that match `question_text` and all the questions that have responses that match `response_text`? I want something like:

```
class QuestionIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    question_text = indexes.CharField(model_attr='question_text')
    response_text = indexes.CharField(model_attr='responses__response_text')
    def get_model(self):
        return Question
```

**Ultimate Question:** How do I index all of `response_text` using this `QuestionIndex` class?

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a [`prepare_` method](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/searchindex_api.html#prepare-foo-self-object) for that field to specify what data is indexed:

```
class QuestionIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    question_text = indexes.CharField(model_attr='question_text')
    response_text = indexes.CharField()

    def prepare_response_text(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([r.response_text for r in obj.responses.all()])
```